# How to plot my dataframe (python & pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I currently have a dataframe (df) which looks like this:
and I need to graph it so it looks like this:

![Desired graph][2]

Where in the graph, the columns are 'index', the blue bars are 'Total' and orange bars are 'Total.1'

And every time I've tried to do it I get KeyErrors, can someone PLEASE point me in the right direction because I feel like I've tried everything but something always goes wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate a simple horizontal stacked bar chart is easy, the below code will accomplish the task.

```
df.set_index('index').plot(stacked=True, kind='barh')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

However, since your labels are so long, the layout will cut off information, and you may want to pre-process your labels so they look better.

---

Here is what I would recommend in terms of plot format:

```
options = {
    'stacked': True,
    'kind': 'barh',
    'title': 'Medals at the Winter and Summer Olympics'
}

df.rename(columns={'Total': 'Winter Games', 'Total.1': 'Summer Games'}).assign(
    code=df['index'].str.extract(r'\((.*?)\)')
).set_index('code')[['Winter Games', 'Summer Games']].plot(**options)

plt.show()
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: When you say fiddle with the massive country labels and add a column for abbreviation, can the column just be numbers 0...x?

Comment: How are you getting it to display the two colours? mine is just coming up as one big blue bar

Comment: The bar has the correct values, but in the top right hand corner my key is only displaying Total.1

Comment: Are you sure you're indexing both columns?

Comment: Yup I used the same .set_index('code')[['Total', 'Total.1']] as you

Comment: And when I print df['Total'] there's definitely something in there, it just won't display in my plot

Comment: Can you post the output of `df.head(10).to_dict()` in your question?

Comment: It's just at the bottom now

Comment: @Michelle, your `Total` column is of type `object` (they are strings), not `int`.  Try `df.Total = df.Total.astype(int)` and then try my code